# According to advaita vedanta how can a formless entity/god do Lila?

Tags: philosophy, vedanta, advaita, leela

> lokavat tu lila kaivalyam [Brahma Sutras - 2.1.33] The creation is
>   merely a sport of Brahman.

How can a formless entity enjoy Lila? Doesn't it sound too nihilistic?

(Note: Lila can also be translated as "past time" which gives it more beautiful purport, and poetic meaning)

How does shankaracharya interpret this?

Comment: Is there any reason for "krishna" tag?

Comment: @KrishnaShweta yup, Krishna is known as Lila purushottama afterall, I wasn't able to find Lila tag.

Comment: We have "leela" tag ^.^

Comment: Leela is for Saguna Brahman not Nirguna Brahman (and there are no two Brahmans). Moreover, Saguna Brahman can be formless.

Comment: @TheDestroyer saguna brahman can be formless?

Comment: @AnubhavJha Why not? You can't see Vishnu now. He is both with form and without form.

Comment: @TheDestroyer this sutra is describing brahman, this would make saguna brahman supreme than nirguna brahman.

Comment: I think it is talking at Vyavharika level, not Paramarthika level.

Comment: @AnubhavJha [This question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/26211/what-is-the-basis-for-the-classification-of-scriptures-as-vyava-harika-pramanya) might be of interest to you as well.

Comment: @AnubhavJha Saguna is neither higher than Nirguna, nor vice versa. Saguna Brahman is the characterization of Guna elements, associating each element of Srishti to fall under Ishwara. To Advaitins, Ishvara is the efficient and material cause of the creation, yet another name for the creative and expressive aspect of the Brahman that is in every living being and everywhere.

Comment: When Guna pervades Brahman, we know it as the Trimurti, which each form (Saguna roop), in charge of a specific aspect of creation - Srishti, Sthiti, Vinaash, which are Sattva, Raja and Tama respectively. Yet the Trimurti is free from Avidya.