# What is the basis for the classification of scriptures as vyava harika pramanya and tattvika pramanya?

Tags: advaita, classification

It is commonly posited in *advaita* that scriptures referring to omniscience and other perfections of Brahman have only relative validity *(vyava harika pramanya)* whilst those speaking of non-dualism alone have absolute validity *(tattvika pramanya)*. What is the basis of this claim? Is it scriptural or merely commentarial?

Comment: see Brahma Sutras 3.2.11-37 available here - https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/brahma-sutras/d/doc62753.html

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Thanks for the link, reading it shows that the classification is commentarial in nature - specifically, this is the interpretation advocated by Shankara in his Bhashya and absent in the Brahma Sutras themselves.